# In Android how to go to first screen without closing current one?

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation

My application contains 4 activities.First main screen has 3 buttons to start other 3 activities.Other activities have home button which should allow user to go to first activity without closing current one and without creating first screen again.How to  go to first screen ?Plz ans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two way the most common variant exists:

1. Use fragment as mentioned above. Read more [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)
2. Without fragments

   `Intent intent = new Intent( context, MainScreenActivity.class );`

   `intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );`

   `current_activity.startActivity( intent );`

And do nothing inside the method `onResume()` and `onStart()` in activity from which you come back

Answer (score 0):

Simple you can use fragments.Change position and it will present always.